# svnsync error - Directory xxx is out of date

Tags: svn, svnsync

While doing an "svnsync synchronize" of a remote repository with big files and a weak connection (Europe vs China), I received the following error:
"svnsync: E160028: Directory '/SourceCode/TPS/1.FSP150CC' is out of date"
This error appears for all further tries and permanently stopped the sync.
I would understand this message for a checkout/update/commit, but it's not logical for an svnsync.

I've already tried:

- checking the mirror with "svnadmin verify" and it validates fine
- copying all revprops to the mirror using "svnsync copy-revprops", but it didn't help
- removing any dead transactions with "svnadmin rmtxns", but is also didn't help

I couldn't find any instances of this specific issue here or on the web, so I'm hoping someone here knows how to fix/workaround this.

Comment: What version of `svnsync` do you use? Run `svnsync --version`.

Comment: version 1.8.17 (r1770682). 
And the OS is CentOS 7.5.1804

Comment: looks similar to the [SVN-2118](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-2118) bug. If it is your case, then upgrading the latest SVN version should help - the bug was partially fixed in 1.9.0: *fsfs: avoid out of date errors from files in a directory changing when
      you change a property on the directory (r1558224)*

Comment: Unfortunately we can't upgrade SVN at the moment - we are running a whole farm of SVN repositories all hosted on 1.8.17 version and doing any upgrade would require a lot of testing and staging work for any backwards-compatibility issues. 

I've also found that the source repository in China is hosted on SVN v1.6.11, which could also cause compatibility issues.

We'll try doing a fresh SVN sync and see it the same error turns up again, while also doing an svn dump as a backup solution. The dump will take ages for a 40 GB repo on the server side, but there doesn't seem to be any other choice

Comment: BTW, you may want to consider [VisualSVN Server with the VDFS replication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/). You will not encounter such issues and VDFS works at least 10 times faster than `svnsync`. Moreover, VDFS was designed with slow WAN links in mind. Just try VisualSVN Server in testing environment and compare it with your current solution - I am pretty sure that you are going to be impressed. ;) PS I am a support engineer with VisualSVN Team.